# Set TAB as shortcut for autocompletion in Emacs Haskell mode

Tags: haskell, emacs, autocomplete

I would like to use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to autocomplete things when I use Haskell REPL (GHCI) in Emacs (invoked with <kbd>C-c C-b</kbd>). <kbd>M-/</kbd> is good enough for me, but I don't know name of this function to bind <kbd>TAB</kbd> to it (<kbd>TAB</kbd> works for tabulation (surprised?) in interactive mode and I found it completely useless).

I wish these changes applied only to interactive mode, not to general editing, when <kbd>TAB</kbd> works for indentation (and possibly for other things, I haven't completely understood everything yet).

Comment: IIRC, `C-h k M-/` should tell you the name of the Lisp function which is bound to `M-/`. After discovering that name, you have to bind `TAB` to it when you are in the interactive mode. I am not fluent enough in elisp to recall how to do this, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding upon @chi's comment, you can find the name of the Lisp function using `C-h k M-/` which gives `hippie-expand` function.

To bind `TAB` in `ghci` interactive mode, use the following elisp code:

```
(define-key haskell-interactive-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'hippie-expand)
```

Or if you want to bind it in normal `haskell-mode` then:

```
(define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'hippie-expand)
```

Comment: It does not work, Emacs says: `Symbol's value as variable is void: haskell-interactive-mode-map`.

Comment: Also, one usually cannot use `(kbd "TAB")` without `<>`.

Comment: @Mark It works for me. The difference between your method and mine seem to be the mode used: You are using `inferior-haskell-mode` for  `ghci` integration whereas I'm using [Interactive-mode](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/wiki/Haskell-Interactive-Mode). The difference is that interactive mode supports more features like cabal sandbox repl, etc.

Comment: Actually, I'm using `haskell-mode` from your link (v.13.07, downloaded form release page).

Comment: @Mark `haskell-mode` has both [interactive and inferior mode](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/wiki).

Comment: I see what you mean now. +1

Answer (score 0):

OK, using [great comment by chi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698022/set-tab-as-shortcut-for-autocompletion-in-emacs-haskell-mode#comment40167561_25698022), I found out that name of the function bound to <kbd>M-/</kbd> is `dabbrev-expand` (via <kbd>C-h k M-/</kbd>).

Now we need name of major mode of Haskell REPL, I found out that we can get it with <kbd>C-h v major-mode</kbd>, it is actually `inferior-haskell-mode`.

Then, I guess there is `inferior-haskell-mode-hook`, which we can use to tweak something when REPL frame gets created.

To add local shortcut binding one should use [`define-key`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Key-Bindings.html). Value of parameter `keymap` can be obtained via `current-local-map`.

Knowing these facts, we can write:

```
(add-hook 'inferior-haskell-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key (current-local-map) (kbd "<tab>") 'dabbrev-expand)))
```

As far as I can tell it works perfectly, now TAB works for autocompletion in REPL mode and for indentation in others.